# Replace duplicated values to NA based on another variable

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to change the value of my df to NA if there are same values with another column

Example df:

```
df1=data.frame(x1=c(1,1,1,2,2,2,2),
               x2=c("a","a","b","b","c","c","c"),
               x3=c("apple","apple","mango","mango","apple","mango","mango"),
               x4=c(10,10,10,10,10,30,30))
```

My expected df:

```
df2=data.frame(x1=c(1,1,1,2,2,2,2), 
               x2=c("a","a","b","b","c","c","c"),
               x3=c("apple","apple","mango","mango","apple","mango","mango"),
               x4=c(10,NA,10,10,10,30,NA))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in base R:

```
is.na(df1$x4) <- duplicated(df1)
df1

  x1 x2    x3 x4
1  1  a apple 10
2  1  a apple NA
3  1  b mango 10
4  2  b mango 10
5  2  c apple 10
6  2  c mango 30
7  2  c mango NA
```

If you do not want to write on `df1`:

```
transform(df1, x4 = `is.na<-`(x4, duplicated(df1)))
  x1 x2    x3 x4
1  1  a apple 10
2  1  a apple NA
3  1  b mango 10
4  2  b mango 10
5  2  c apple 10
6  2  c mango 30
7  2  c mango NA
```

Answer (score 1):

You could `group_by` and `replace` the `duplicated`s like this:

```r
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
  group_by(x1, x2, x3) %>%
  mutate(x4 = replace(x4, duplicated(x4), NA))
#> # A tibble: 7 × 4
#> # Groups:   x1, x2, x3 [5]
#>      x1 x2    x3       x4
#>   <dbl> <chr> <chr> <dbl>
#> 1     1 a     apple    10
#> 2     1 a     apple    NA
#> 3     1 b     mango    10
#> 4     2 b     mango    10
#> 5     2 c     apple    10
#> 6     2 c     mango    30
#> 7     2 c     mango    NA
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-10 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Similar to @Quinten using `ifelse`:

```
library(dplyr)

df1 %>%
  group_by(x1, x2, x3) %>%
  mutate(x4 = ifelse(duplicated(x4), NA, x4)) %>%
  ungroup()

    x1 x2    x3       x4
  <dbl> <chr> <chr> <dbl>
1     1 a     apple    10
2     1 a     apple    NA
3     1 b     mango    10
4     2 b     mango    10
5     2 c     apple    10
6     2 c     mango    30
7     2 c     mango    NA
```